# Making a POST request through WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I have been on this for a week now. I am trying to make a POST request using WKWebview. This has been achieved on the android version seamlessly.

Replicating the same on iOS with SwiftUI has been a ton of complications.

I want the form to be submitted onload and redirect to the payment gate way web for authorization but it appears something is cancelling the request

I have tried to loadHTML through the webview but it did not work

```swift
public struct HTMLView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: String
    var javascriptString: String
    @Binding var webViewUIModel: UIModel
    
    public init(url: String, javascriptString: String = "", webViewUIModel: Binding<UIModel>) {
        self.url = url
        self.javascriptString = javascriptString
        self._webViewUIModel = webViewUIModel
    }
    public func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            webView.loadHTMLString(url, baseURL: nil)
        }
        return webView
    }
    
    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uiView.loadHTMLString(url, baseURL: nil)
        }
    }
    public func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewCordinator {
        .init(javascriptString: javascriptString) {
            print("HTMLView: Start")
        } didHaveError: { e in
            print("HTMLView: Error")
        } didFinish: {
            print("HTMLView: Finish")
        }
    }
}
public class WebViewCordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var javascriptString: String
    var didStart: () -> Void
    var didHaveError: (Error) -> Void
    var didFinish: () -> Void
    
    public init(javascriptString: String = "",didStart: @escaping () -> Void, didHaveError: @escaping (Error) -> Void, didFinish: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.javascriptString = javascriptString
        self.didStart = didStart
        self.didHaveError = didHaveError
        self.didFinish = didFinish
    }

    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) async {
        print("HTMLViewREDIRECT \(await webView.url)")
    }
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        didHaveError(error)
    }
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) async {
        print("HTMLViewCOMMIT \(await webView.url)")
    }
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) async {
        print("HOST \(navigationAction.request)")
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        
    }
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse) async -> WKNavigationResponsePolicy {
        let response = navigationResponse.response

        print("HTMLViewResponse \(response)")
        return .allow
    }
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) async {
        print( "HTMLViewFINISH \(await navigation)")
        print( "HTMLViewFINISH \(await String(describing: webView.url))")
        
        if !javascriptString.isEmpty {
            await webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptString) { value, error in
                print(self.javascriptString)
                print(value)
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        didFinish()
    }
}
```

But I get this error `2023-02-06 16:49:22.994531+0000 TrialsProject[89459:6286324] [ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke` at the end of the request.

I also tried using URLSession

```swift
                   var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
                    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
                    request.allowsCellularAccess = true
                    request.httpMethod = "POST"
//                    let params =
                    request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

                    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in
                        print("Response \(response)")
                            if data != nil {
                                if let returnString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                                   print("Returned String \(returnString)")
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    task.resume()
```

But I get `NSURLErrorDomain error code -999`

What can I do to achieve a POST request with WKWebview?